# UploadComplete event not triggering in plupload

Tags: javascript, php, upload, plupload

I'm using plupload to upload files and I'm trying to get files name after UploadComplete event but no success.

I can get the file name in FilesAdded event using this code:

```
init: {
FilesAdded : function (up, files) {

for ( var i in files) {
                        files[i].name = files[i].name.split( '_' ).join( ' ' ).trim();
alert(files[i].name);

           }
           },
```

but I'm not being able to get file name after upload completed. here is what I have tried:

```
UploadComplete: function(up, files) {
for ( var i in files) {
                        files[i].name = files[i].name.split( '_' ).join( ' ' ).trim();
alert(files[i].name);
}
            },
}
});
```

Any helping hand will be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Plupload are you trying this in? Seems to work fine in v2.3.4 (at least). Check the sample [here](http://play.plupload.com/aaaaal/2).